# Find all algebras with one binary operation and the set {0,1}

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binary-operations, algebras

I believe the only algebra is (A,*). +,-,/ don't meet the requirements. But how do I prove that there is no other? 
What are all the binary operations on numbers?

Answer (score 0):

With no conditions, a binary operation is an arbitrary function $A\times A\to A$. There are $4$ elements in $A\times A$ and two elements in $A$, so there are $2^4=16$ possible binary operations. To enumerate them, write
$$A\times A=\{(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)\}$$
and assign all possible sequences of values to this.

Comment: Understand the count but how do I find all the specific binary operations?

Comment: @MichalRickwood Just list the possible values. Arrange the elements in order, and assign the sequences of $1$'s and $0$'s to them. For example, $0000$ would mean everything is $0$, $1010$ means $(0,0)\mapsto 1$, $(1,0)\mapsto 1$, and everything else to $0$.

Comment: @MichalRickwood This is just using the suggestion in my answer, placing the elements in that order and assigning values to them.